# How to align-left labels wrapped on two rows

Tags: css

I have an unordered list of labels. I would like to align them in CSS on the left side like on this picture (I can't post images for now):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1WHJ.png

But so far I was able to achieve just this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCTM.png

```html
<ul class="badge-list">
  <li>Sci-Fi</li>
  <li>Adventure</li>
  <li>Crime</li>
  <li>Novels</li>
  <li>Children</li>
  <li>Drama</li>
  <li>Historical</li>
</ul>
```

Styles:

```css
.badge-list {
  .li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .li+.li {margin-left: 5px}
}
```

How can I left-align the second row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.li+.li {margin-left: 5px}` was the problem, inserting a margin to the left. Why not put margin to their right? `.li {margin-right: 5px}`